# Getting the min and max values of a raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

What is the recommended approach to get the min and max pixel values of a raster in Google Earth Engine?

Let's take this example, in which I use the CHIRPS precipitation raster to sum up values for an entire year for a given country.

```
var rainfall2019 = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD')
                  .select('precipitation')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')
                  .sum()
                  .clip(country);

var rainfall_palette = 'ff0000, ffffff, 0000ff';

var vis = {
  min: ???,
  max: ???,
  palette: rainfall_palette
};

Map.addLayer(rainfall2019, vis);
```

Now, how will I know what to add for min and max (in the above snippet I added 3 question marks)?

In a GIS I would just open the raster's properties window.

What I found is something like this:

```
var max = rainfall2019.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), country);
var min = rainfall2019.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), country);
print('max', max);
print('min', min);
```

Although this does work, it often randomly gives me an error, making me wonder if it is the correct approach:

[image]

Comment: When using reduce regions, if you don't specify the scale or a crs and crs transform, it will perform the calculations using a geographic coordinate system rather than a projected coordinate system. If you know the spatial resolution of the dataset then you could add it
`var max = rainfall2019.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(), 
geometry: country,
scale: ???
});
`
[https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregion]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need to specify the scale or crs & crs-transform.
In th e following code, just put the resolution of your data (instead of 10) and you will have the min and the max:

```
var minMax = rainfall2019.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
      geometry: country, 
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
print(minMax)
```